# Distinct counts from large table are too slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, count, distinct, postgresql-performance

I have a table with 1.2 billion rows. The table has 60-70 columns, the vast majority of which are empty.

The table is indexed on `subscription_id`, among other indexes.

My query is:

```
SELECT count(distinct listing_id)
FROM apps
WHERE subscription_id = 1298;
```

This particular `subscription_id` is going to have roughly 30M rows to count. Unfortunately I am unable to do so as the query takes in excess of one hour just to  get that count.

I know there must be some way to improve it. Would it be improved if I created an index on `subscription_id` and `listing_id` together?

Comment: Please edit to include the info listed here:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Can you maybe include `EXPLAIN SELECT count(distinct listing_id) FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."subscription_id" = 1298` in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would it be improved if I created an index on `subscription_id` and `listing_id` together?

Possibly yes, an index on `(subscription_id, listing_id)` (columns in this order!) *might* very well allow a cheaper index-only scan. You did not provide enough information to say more.

***If*** it's all about *this particular `subscription_id`*, then a [**partial index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) would help a lot more:

```
CREATE INDEX ON apps (listing_id) WHERE subscription_id = 1298;
```

**If** there are more than a few duplicate `listing_id` per `subscription_id`, use 
this adapted query with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE rcte AS (
   (
   SELECT listing_id
   FROM   apps
   WHERE  subscription_id = 1298
   ORDER  BY listing_id
   LIMIT  1
   )

   UNION ALL
   SELECT a.listing_id
   FROM   rcte r
   JOIN   LATERAL (
      SELECT a.listing_id
      FROM   apps a
      WHERE  a.subscription_id = 1298
      AND    a.listing_id > r.listing_id
      ORDER  BY a.listing_id
      LIMIT  1
      ) a ON a.listing_id IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT count(*) FROM rcte;
```

Requires index from above to be fast. For many duplicates it can be faster by **orders of magnitude**. The point is to work around a still missing (up to Postgres 12) index skip scan. See:

- [Fast way to count distinct column values (using an index?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57560949/939860)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25536748/939860)

**If**, OTOH, there are ***no*** duplicate `listing_id`, then get rid of `DISTINCT` to make it a lot faster.